# Do Jehovah's Witnesses have one Saviour or Two?

Tags: soteriology, jehovahs-witnesses

Jehovah's witnesses firmly believe that Jehovah and Jesus are separate beings and that Jesus is NOT God because Jesus is an angel.  What do JW's say about their Saviour?  Specifically,

- Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21 emphatically declare that Jehovah is the one and only Saviour and "besides me there is no Saviour"

Yet we also read numerous references in the New Testament that Jesus is the only name by which we can be saved and that Jesus is the Saviour of the world.  Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11.

Therefore, do Jehovah's Witnesses have one saviour or two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jehovah’s Witnesses have only one principal Savior, Jehovah God.  Jesus Christ is exalted as the “Chief Agent and Savior (Acts 5:31) because it is THROUGH Jesus that salvation is accomplished:

> Savior - Insight on the Scriptures, Volume 2: ***Jehovah is identified as the principal Savior, the only Source of deliverance.*** (Isa 43:11; 45:21) He was the Savior and Deliverer of Israel, time and again. (Ps 106:8, 10, 21; Isa 43:3; 45:15; Jer 14:8)...  When Jesus was on earth, Jehovah was his Savior, supporting and strengthening him to maintain integrity through his strenuous trials.—Heb 5:7; Ps 28:8.
>
> Along with his role as Savior, Jehovah is also the “Repurchaser.” (Isa 49:26; 60:16) In the past he redeemed his people Israel from captivity. In delivering Christians from sin’s bondage, he does the repurchasing through his Son ***Jesus Christ*** (1Jo 4:14), Jehovah’s provision for salvation, who ***is therefore exalted as “Chief Agent and Savior.”*** (Ac 5:31) Accordingly, Jesus Christ can rightly be called “our Savior,” even though ***he performs the salvation as the agent of Jehovah.*** (Tit 1:4; 2Pe 1:11) The name Jesus, given to God’s Son by angelic direction, means “Jehovah Is Salvation,” for, said the angel, “he will save his people from their sins.” (Mt 1:21; Lu 1:31) This name points out that ***Jehovah is the Source of salvation, accomplished through Jesus.*** For this reason we find the Father and the Son spoken of together in connection with salvation.—Tit 2:11-13; 3:4-6.  Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200003848
>
> What Is God’s Way to Salvation? Watchtower 1960:  ***As mankind’s source of salvation Jehovah God*** provided the perfect man, whose life could ransom the human race, by transferring the life force of his chief angelic Son in the heavens to the womb of a virgin. Because the child that was born did not receive its life through Adam’s line of descent but from God, it was perfect. Thus Jesus Christ became equal to Adam and able to ransom mankind by laying down his perfect human life. “Just as the Son of man came, not to be ministered to, but to minister and to give his soul [or life] a ransom in exchange for many.”—Matt. 20:28.  Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1960161#h=14

(Emphasis mine)

EDIT: I have deleted the part of my answer that caused offense and would refer instead to the 22 October 1976 Awake article, ‘How Many Saviors Do You Have?’ and invite people to read the article in its entirety to get the Jehovah’s Witness perspective, part of which says this:

> Salvation belongs to Jehovah,” declared the inspired psalmist. (Ps. 3:8) Through his prophet Isaiah, the Almighty stated: “I—I am Jehovah, and besides me there is no savior.”—Isa. 43:11.  But it may be asked: ‘Is not Jesus Christ the Savior? So, then, are not Jehovah and Jesus the same, making our Savior but one, God?’  But what about Jesus Christ? He, too, cannot be spoken of as being a Savior besides Jehovah, that is, as a rival of his Father.   The Scriptures clearly establish that Jesus’ role as Savior was assigned to him by his Father...  Because salvation comes from Jehovah God through Jesus Christ, a “great crowd” (standing before the throne and in front of the Lamb) is depicted in the book of Revelation as making the following declaration: “Salvation we owe to our God, who is seated on the throne, and to the Lamb.” (Rev. 7:9, 10) Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/101976768
>   Here are the relevant Bible verses from the New World Translation:
>
> Psalm 130:8 NWT: “And he himself [Jehovah] will redeem Israel...”
>
> Luke 2:11 NWT: “because there was born to you today a Savior, who is Christ the Lord”
>
> 2 Timothy 1:9-10 NWT: “This was given us in [connection with] Christ Jesus before times longlasting, but it has now been clearly evident through the manifestation of our Savior, Christ Jesus...”
>
> Titus 1:3 NWT: “under command of our Savior, God.”
>
> Jude 25 NWT: “To the only God our Savior through Jesus Christ our Lord, be glory, majesty, might and authority for all past eternity and now and into all eternity. Amen.”

Jehovah is identified as the principal Savior, but Jesus Christ is called “our Savior,” even though he performs the salvation as the agent of Jehovah.  Jehovah is the Source of salvation, accomplished through Jesus.  That is the official view of Jehovah’s Witnesses.  I think that means they have only one Saviour.

Comment: When you say "our Savior," who do you have in mind? At Ps. 130:8 who or what is "Israel"?    Who is the "savior" here - Ephesians 5:23 "Christ is head of the congregation, he being a savior of this body." ?   & Acts 5:31 "God exalted this one as Chief Agent AND Savior to his right hand, to give repentance to Israel and forgiveness of sins." ?

Comment: @ethos – Jehovah’s Witnesses say Jehovah is their principal Savior but Jesus is called “our Savior,” even though he performs the salvation as the agent of Jehovah. Jehovah is the Source of their salvation, accomplished through Jesus. That is the official view of Jehovah’s Witnesses.  If you want to know what they think about “Israel” (or any other related question about Savior) then you should post a question seeking their views.  Any such discussion here would be inappropriate.

Comment: So the answer to you question above is; Yes, we do have two saviours.

Comment: @ethos - No, that is not my answer. My answer is that from what their literature says, Jehovah God is their principal Savor, the source of their salvation, which is accomplished through Jesus. Please do not attempt to put words into my mouth. If you disagree with what they have published in their literature (as quoted by me with links to follow) then you should post a question to seek further insights. End of discussion.